# unable to install xamarin from vs 2015 setup

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have vs 2015 upgrade 1 installed and I try to install Xamrin from the setup, but when I try to install it, at the end receive this error message:

C#/.Net Xamarin
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with package. The error code is 2711.

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error. The error is due to old Xamarin installer files in the cache.

*C#/.Net Xamarin The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with package. The error code is 2711.*

I did the following steps to fix it:

*Note:* a folder could be hidden, so enable show *hidden items* in the windows explorer.

1. Delete any Xamarin related folders from 
   "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\installers" folder.

For example:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\installers\XamarinVS

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\installers\XamarinVSV1

2. If the first step doesn't help then try to do the following below.

Delete all Xamarin related folders or  files from windows temprorary folders TMP and TEMP.

You could find the temprorary folders in the Windows/Control Panel/ System/Advanced/Enviroment variables

I found that solution in comments section here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/03/31/mobile-app-development-made-easy-with-visual-studio-and-xamarin/#comment-142062

Comment: yes, found the same solution just yesterday. the problems was the old installer

Answer (score 1):

You can try a manual install by downloading and installing the following:

http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.0.1.147.msi