# Xamarin project template in VS2015 update 2 seems inconsistent with the Microsoft eBook

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

First of all I am pretty excited to learn that Xamarin is free to all, so I cannot wait to upgraded by Visual Studio 2015 Community edition to update 2, which comes with the Xamarin.

I also downloaded the free eBook from Microsoft https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2016/03/31/free-ebook-creating-mobile-apps-with-xamarin-forms/ and I decided to play with it. Chapter 2 (page 21) I read

> In Visual Studio, select the menu option File > New > Project. At the
>   left of the New Project dialog, select Visual C# and then
>   Cross-Platform.

But when I opened my VS2015, I only see the project templates
[image]

I cannot see that `Cross-Platform` template at all. But I still browsed around and thought `Mobile Apps` might be the closest one. So I followed the book again

> For now, pick the first one: Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable) in
>   Visual Studio or Use Portable Class Library in Xamarin Studio.
>
> If you’re running Visual Studio, six projects are created: one common
>   project (the PCL project) and five application projects. For a
>   solution named Hello, these are:

And the projects created (assume I use "Hello" as solution name) should include `Hello.Droid`, `Hello.iOS`, `Hello.UWP`, `Hello.Windows`, `Hello.WinPhone`. But what I see from my VS is only
[image]

What do I miss here? How to include UWP in my Xamarin solution from VS2015 update 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the old templates for some reason. You may need to reinstall Visual Studio to get the current ones. I have a relatively fresh installation of Visual Studio w/ Update 2, and my templates match what the book says.

When I use this template, it does in fact create a UWP and Windows project in addition to WP 8.1, iOS and Android.

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, let me uninstall everything and try again.

Comment: By the way, the templates you seem to have are what used to be installed with Xamarin 3.

Comment: I completely (or at least I think I have completely) uninstalled VS2015, and reinstall it. The result is even worse, the whole Xamarin templates are gone. I guess the setup is just too buggy, it failed once because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805135/unable-to-install-xamarin-from-vs-2015-setup then it failed again because Android SDK could not be installed. I will figure something more.

Answer (score 2):

UWP isn't part of the default template, you need to create a new Universal project, then add a reference to Xamarin Forms.

You can follow this guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/

Comment: It looks like the information in that eBook is not accurate at all. And I followed your link to add the universal project, it seems that it has nothing to do with Xamarin by default, I have to manually reference to it by including the Nuget package.

Comment: Xamarin Forms for UWP is still currently in preview and hence why I think they left it out of the default template at the moment. Windows based projects are just based off the default Windows Mobile project templates already available in VS and they just add references to XF and a bit of initialization code.